# How to (use package exsheets to) make a exercise section at the end of each section or subsection like the following?

Tags: counters, exercises, exsheets

PS: exsheets isn't a must, all methods are welcome.

My document structure:

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Introduction to Latex}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{first}
        \section{start}
            \subsection{install}
        \section{keyword}
    \chapter{second}
        \section{improve}
\end{document}
```

I want that:
If a section have at least one subsection, then the exercise section is like the following.

[image]

If a section doesn't have any subsection, then the exercise section is like the following.
[image]

As I have shown, Exercises are counted in each chapter.
I am new to latex so that I read the documentation of exsheets and still don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think that the images are in the wrong order. BTW, `exsheets` is a requirement for any other reason?  or no matter the cat if he  hunt this mouse ?

Comment: @Fran exsheets isn't a must. All methods are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An  approach using custom environments with custom lists. The exercises in the subsection have a different indentation so you can compare how is adjusted.

I am not sure if you want the exercises in a  colored box, in this case, uncomment the three  lines with the word `tcolorbox` for a start.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{qcounter}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\title{The art of make something}
\date{}\author{}
\def\df{Lore ipsum dolor sit amet. } % You guessed! Just print dummy text

\newenvironment{questions}{%
%\begin{tcolorbox}
\bigskip\noindent{\bfseries\large Exercises section \thesection:}
\begin{list}
{{\bfseries Exercise \thesection.\arabic{qcounter}:}}{
\setlength\labelwidth{-1em}
\setlength\labelsep{1em}
\setlength\leftmargin{0cm}
\usecounter{qcounter}}}{\end{list}
%\end{tcolorbox}
} 

\newenvironment{subquestions}{
\bigskip\noindent{\bfseries Exercises section \thesubsection:}
\begin{list}
{{\bfseries Exercise \thesubsection.\arabic{qcounter}:}}{
\setlength\labelwidth{8em}
\setlength\labelsep{1em}
\setlength\leftmargin{12em}
\usecounter{qcounter}}}{\end{list}} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{General programming}

\df\df\df\df\df\par

\begin{questions}
\item \df\df\df\df
\item \df\df\df\df\df\df\df  
\item \df\df
\item \df
\end{questions}

\subsection{Phyton language}

\df\df\df\df\df\par

\begin{subquestions}
\item \df\df\df\df
\item \df\df\df\df
\item \df\df
\item \df
\end{subquestions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The counter seems not right. Exercises should be counted in a chapter . In addition, if I need to define environment, I hope that environment will automatically derive whether this section has a subsection, ie:, I only need to use \begin{questions} \end{questions}

Comment: @K.Robert If you are using `\chapter{}`, and the first number of each exercise should be the counter of `\chapter`  + the number of the item  only, no matter is if the list is in a section or a subsection, then you only have to change  `Exercise \thesection.\arabic{qcounter}` by `Exercise \thechapter .\arabic{qcounter}`. Right?

Comment: still can't get the expected result@Fran

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special to consider with `exsheets`: change the counter setting and choose `runin` template. No need for custom environments in order to change the name form *Question* to *Exercise*.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within={chapter} ,
  counter-format=\thechapter.qu[1] ,
  headings = runin ,
  question/name = Exercise
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}
\section{start}
\subsection{Exercises Section}

\begin{question}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{question}

\section{Exercises Section}
\begin{question}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Getting the colon after the exercise number requires a bit more work, though:

```
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myrunin}{default}{
  runin = true ,
  number-post-code = \textbf{:}\space ,
  attach = { main[l,vc]points[l,vc](\linewidth+\marginparsep,0pt) } ,
  join = {
    main[r,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]number[l,vc](.333em,0pt)
  }
}

\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within={chapter} ,
  counter-format=\thechapter.qu[1] ,
  headings = myrunin ,
  question/name = Exercise
}
```

---

The same (including the colon) using `xsim`, `exsheets` designated successor package. At first sight this looks more complicated but indeed it is more flexible as changes to the layout are much easier to achieve:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xsim,needspace}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{runin}
  {%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}:}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} % <<< notice the space
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
        \marginpar{%
          \printgoal{\PropertyValue}%
          \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{+\printgoal{\PropertyValue}}%
          \,\IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
              {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
              {\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/the-counter = \thechapter.\arabic{exercise} ,
  exercise/template = runin
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}
\section{start}
\subsection{Exercises Section}

\begin{exercise}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{exercise}

\section{Exercises Section}
\begin{exercise}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming
  convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page~2.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Introduction to Latex}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-within={chapter},counter-format=\thechapter.qu[1]}
\newenvironment{myquestion}
  {\question[name={Exercise}]}
  {\endquestion}


\newlength{\currentparindent}
\newenvironment{myset}
    {   \setlength{\currentparindent}{\parindent}
        \par
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{\currentparindent}
         \noindent\textbf{Exercise Section \thesubsection  }
        }
    {

       \end{minipage}
    }  

\begin{document}
    \chapter{first}
        \section{start}
            \subsection{install}
                \begin{myset}
                 \begin{myquestion}
                Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page 2.
            \end{myquestion}
             \begin{myquestion}
                Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page 2.
            \end{myquestion}
                \end{myset}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is my answer, but I still don't know how to avoid line feeds between the title and the content of the exercises.